# How can I transfer music from Amazon Prime Music to Google Play Music without downloading and re-uploading?

Tags: google-play-music, amazon-music

The core of this problem is I really want to avoid using the Music Manager ever, at all. It's already wreaked so much havok on my local music collection that I'm not sure it's worth the trouble of finding and deleting all the duplicate download files and fixing all the metadata again, so I'm just giving up and going to use their cloud service exclusively. (Was that their plan all along?)

I do plan to do most of my purchasing from Google Play in the future so as to avoid the necessity of transferring stuff from Amazon, but I'm gonna get Amazon gift cards a lot more often than I'm gonna get Google gift cards, so...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As with transfers between almost any two competing applications, transferring music from Amazon Music to Google Play Music is not as simple as clicking a couple buttons. You are unfortunately going to need to download from Amazon and then upload to Google.

*However*, you do not *have* to use Music Manager to upload music to Google Play. While, in my own experience, uploading using Music Manager tends to be quite a bit faster (when it works like it's supposed to), if you have Google Chrome and have also installed the [Google Play Music for Chrome app](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-play-music/fahmaaghhglfmonjliepjlchgpgfmobi), you can open up Play Music in Chrome and simply **drag your downloaded Amazon music files from your file browser and drop them into the Play Music tab**; this commences the uploading process, which uses Chrome itself rather than a dedicated client like Music Manager, for whatever you dropped in.

For more information on uploading using Chrome and its official Play Music app, check out this [Google Play Help Center article](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/4627259).

Comment: I actually do use something like this now. I have the Google Play Chrome app watch a folder that Amazon music downloads to and then I tell the Amazon app to always download. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the previous poster is correct,  I am not aware of a way to do this cloud to cloud - if someone does,  please speak up.

However, if you're willing to do a little setup in your house,  you can have a pretty seamless experience.

I buy almost all of my music from Amazon, because they have the best deals, larger library,  and they auto upgrade the audio resolution for you when  they get better copies of their files.

I,  however,  play almost all of my music via Google Play Music. The interface is superb,  as are the organizational principals,  and playlist curation.

So,  my solution is pretty simple. I have a server in my home running Windows 7 for various reasons. I have Amazon music manager running and set to download all new purchases to a specific directory. I have Google's music manager running all the time as well and looking at that same directory for new deposits. When it sees a new music folder if uploads it to Google play music.

The end result is that I can be on phone anywhere in the world, buy music on the Amazon app (or,  more magically,. Hit the buy from Amazon button in Shazam),  and the purchase goes thru,  downloads it to my house the  reloads it to the Google cloud. The music appears in my Google play library within a few minutes. Poof.

Therw is an additional advantages, in that I now have three copies of all of music: Amazon,  Google,  and my home server. Overly redundant,  yes,  but... Uh... I'm quite anal that way.

Comment: Do you know how to do the reverse task? To transfer playlists from Google Music to Amazon?